# Cypress assertion - how to log result (or do extra action) after an assertion

Tags: javascript, cypress, assertion

I am writing an test automation feature. I would like to save the test result to my testplan through API.
For example, I would like to be able to achieve something like below

```
      let b = expect(3).eql(4).then((result)=> {
        cy.updateTestResult(result, testCaseId)
      })
```

However, there is no '.then()' for what's returned by assertion.
I think I can probably write an if/else, but I think it's kinda of ugly since I need to repeat the logic twice.
Any suggestions are welcome, thank you !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can do something like

```
....

expect(3).to.eql(4);

// will only get here if the above passes
cy.request('POST', 'http://somehost/some-url', { some: 'json-data-here' }).then(
  (response) => {
    // ensure you got a 200 back from api call
    expect(response.status).to.eq(200);
  }
)
```

To not have to do this manually ever time, you might be able to use `afterEach`, but I am not sure you will get the info on the test itself or if it passed/failed

Comment: Yes, your feedback is exactly the same solution as what I did, I have also updated my final solution below. Tks !

Answer (score 0):

@Olore
Update with my final solution here:

```
...

it('Remove VDC', () => {
    cy.delete_vdc_v2(eccData, vdc)
    .then(() => {
      expect(1).to.equal(2)
      testResult = TEST_STATUS.PASS
    })
  });

});

afterEach('Update Test Result', () => {  
  cy.updateTestResult(testResult, testRunId, testCaseId, testPointId)
});
```